# How to exclude directories from Mozy custom backup sets using spotlight queries

Tags: macos, spotlight, mozy

I would like to create custom backup sets for Mozy which exclude certain directories. For example, I would like to backup my Itunes folder, but exclude all podcasts. I have created a backup set which searches in /Users/me/Music and used this query

```
kMDItemPath == "*Podcasts*"wc
```

to exclude all matching files. However, nothing matches. Queries which use the kMDItemFSName spotlight attribute work fine, but any query using kMDItemPath doesn't seem to work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341590/no-results-in-spotlight-in-searches-against-kmditempath/1342019#1342019) in StackOverflow (I'm quoting [kperryua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72126/kperryua)):

Quoth the documentation:

> kMDItemPath
>
> Complete path to the file. This value
>   of this attribute can be retrieved,
>   but can't be used in a query or to
>   sort search results.

[Link](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40001694-SW1)

That means that the attribute `kMDItemPath` can only be used with a MDItem or NSMetadataItem to retrieve the path for an item already found. You cannot use it with an MDQuery or an NSMetadataQuery within the query predicate you specify to find files.